# Dynamically create button and then remove that button when clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

lHi,

I have some divs in a html doc and when I click the div I am adding a button.  eg attached:

HTML:

```
<div class="week">
     <div class="day wk1" id="day1">   
          <label for="day1">Test</label>       
      </div>
      <div class="day wk1" id="day2">  
          <label for="day2">Test</label>       
      </div>
```

When I add a button by clicking on the div, no problem.

Add Button:

```
$(".day").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var check = $("#day7").width() - 2;
        var insert = $(this).prop("id");
        insert = `#${insert}`;
        var par = $('<br class="break"><button class="testing">').html('Shift Manual Insert').width(check).css("background-color", "green");
        par.appendTo(insert);
        // console.log(insert);
    });
```

When I remove the button by clicking on it it does remove it but simultaneously adds a new button as per the code above and below.

Remove Button:

```
$(".day").on('click','.testing', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".break").remove;
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

I am sure I am doing something silly but for the life of me, I cannot figure it out? Please ignore my incorrect use of id's and classes, this is purely a test to gain experience.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Kind regards

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is present inside the div. So when you click the button, your div click event is also fired. This is due to event bubbling. Check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

```
$(".day").on('click','.testing', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".break").remove;
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The event is getting propagated from the `click` handler on dom with `.testing` class to it's parent that is dom with `.day` class. `.day` have another click handler which add the element.So after removing the element again `$(".day").click(function(e) {` is getting fired which is adding back the `button` element

Replace`e.preventDefault();` with `e.stopPropagation();` in the `click` handler of `.testing`

```js
$(".day").click(function(e) {
  console.log('x')
  e.preventDefault();
  var check = $("#day7").width() - 2;
  var insert = $(this).prop("id");
  insert = `#${insert}`;
  var par = $('<br class="break"><button class="testing">').html('Shift Manual Insert').width(check).css("background-color", "green");
  par.appendTo(insert);
  // console.log(insert);
});


$(".day").on('click', '.testing', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".break").remove;
  $(this).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day wk1" id="day1">
    <label for="day1">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div class="day wk1" id="day2">
    <label for="day2">Test</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a short explanation why this fixes it?